# How do I see detailed logs in Heroku, similar to the logs I see in my dev environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

In my dev environment, when I make a request on my app, I see the AREL & SQL queries like this:

```
Started GET "/products/20" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-31 19:18:40 -0500
Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"20"}
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" LIMIT 6
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "20"]]
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" 
  Vendor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 11 LIMIT 1
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."vendor_id" = 11
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "category_products" ON "categories"."id" = "category_products"."category_id" WHERE "category_products"."product_id" = 20
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "category_products" ON "categories"."id" = "category_products"."category_id" WHERE "category_products"."product_id" = 20
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 11 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" WHERE "vendors"."id" = 11 LIMIT 1
  Rendered products/_similar_products.html.erb (6.1ms)
  Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (71.2ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'superadmin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
  Rendered layouts/_login_nav.html.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (76.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1171ms (Views: 1160.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

But this is the same query on Heroku:

```
2013-01-01T00:24:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/products/20" for 67.230.41.62 at 2013-01-01 00:24:57 +0000
2013-01-01T00:24:58+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/products/20 host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd=67.230.41.62 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=59ms status=200 bytes=7718
```

I am tailing my Heroku logs by doing `heroku logs --tail`, that's how I am getting that info.

Is it possible to get the same type of logs that I see in my dev environment on Heroku?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

In my `config/environment.rb` I put this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

In `config/environment/production.rb` I put this:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

Comment: Please update your answer with exactly the code you've put in various config files, so we can see what might need to be done.

Answer (score 5):

On older stacks, Heroku inserts a plugin into your app that reconfigures the logger to fit into Heroku's setup. This plugin uses the `LOG_LEVEL` environment variable to set the logging level used (whatever is in your app's config is ignored)

Update that environment variable to DEBUG and you should see the extra info.

With current stacks, you should use the `rails_12factor` gem, that redirects log output to stdout, where Heroku expects to find it.

Comment: D'oh.  I forgot I'd done this as well when I got it working.  Looks like this is done [here](https://github.com/ddollar/rails_log_stdout/blob/master/init.rb#L7).

Comment: Wait, I wonder why it worked for my test app, then.  Going to have to investigate...

Answer (score 2):

There's a log_level setting in the per environment initializers ({development,staging,production}.rb).  In production and staging it is either commented or set to :info.  Set it to :debug.

Also, add

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

to the bottom of your config/environment.rb.

Comment: Would it change it immediately or would I have to do something to trigger that change? As far as I know, once I push a new commit it restarts the server. Should that be enough?

Comment: Yes, restarting is sufficient.

Comment: The reason I asked is because even though I did that, it is still giving me the same output :(

Comment: Thought that might happen.  There are sometimes some other settings needed.  I'll have the answer updated for you in a little bit with something that I've tested.

Comment: Ok Thanks! Would love to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Tested it, and it's working for me on heroku.  Try the new version and let me know if it doesn't work/accept if it does. =D

Comment: That still doesn't work for me :( Still seeing very terse log output. I will be AFK for a few hours, so if you reply shortly after I write this I probably won't see it until tomorrow. Just thought I would give you a heads-up so you aren't waiting for a quick reply :)

Comment: I updated the question with the things I have tried in my various files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22028/discussion-between-tehgeekmeister-and-marcamillion)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to production.rb

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```